# Passing multiple arguments for callback function in java from native c code (JNI)

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

Below code calls a callback function in java from native c code passing some string data as argument.

Native C layer

```
jmethodID statusId = env->GetMethodID(pctx->jniHelperClz, "CallbackHandler", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
jstring string_data = env->NewStringUTF((const char*)"SOME_STRING_DATA");
env->CallVoidMethod(pctx->jniHelperObj, statusId, string_data);
env->DeleteLocalRef(string_data);
```

Android / Java (Callback handler)

```
@Keep
private void CallbackHandler(String string_data) {
    // Some Code
}
```

Along with string I want to pass a int type data also. My java Callback handler looks like below. What should I change in my native layer to support two arguments.

```
@Keep
private void CallbackHandler(String string_data, int int_data) {
    // Some Code
}
```

Comment: so add `jint` parameter when calling `CallVoidMethod` - its signature is: `void CallVoidMethod(jobject obj, jmethodID methodID, ...)`

Comment: You need to edit the arguments of function pointer `CallVoidMethod` to have an extra `int` in the structure `env`.

Comment: Last argument of GetMethodID i.e. ("(Ljava/lang/String;)V”) must also be changed right?

Comment: right: signature has to be changed as well - use `javap` to print it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change method signature from `(Ljava/lang/String;)V` to `(Ljava/lang/String;I)V`:

```
jmethodID statusId = env->GetMethodID(pctx->jniHelperClz, “CallbackHandler”, "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V”);
```

Also, you use `DeleteLocalRef()` not proper way. This method used to delete the local references created via `NewLocalRef()`, but `NewStringUTF()` not create them. Method `NewStringUTF()` create `jstring` object in java heap which under garbage collector control. You don't need to delete this manually.

Take note:

> Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call. They are **freed automatically** after the native method returns. Each local reference costs some amount of Java Virtual Machine resource. Programmers need to make sure that native methods do not excessively allocate local references. Although local references are automatically freed after the native method returns to Java, excessive allocation of local references may cause the VM to run out of memory during the execution of a native method.

You need to use `DeleteLocalRef()` to immediately delete large objects (for example in loop).

Comment: _"They are freed automatically after the native method returns"_ The OP is calling Java from native code, not the other way around. The local reference will not be deleted automatically if the native method doesn't return back to Java (or if/when the native thread is detached from the VM).

Comment: Interesting think, @Michael. Where I can read more about this? May be you have link to code example?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any good documentation describing this. But you could look at Android's runtime implementation to understand what will happen in different circumstances, e.g. Jni.cpp and Thread.cpp in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/kitkat-mr1-release/vm (yes, Android uses Art instead of Dalvik nowadays, but the Dalvik source code is generally easier to navigate).

Comment: Thanks for link, @Michael. I did not expect you suggest to read full source code of android platform :)

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. Below code worked for me.

`methodID statusId = env->GetMethodID(pctx->jniHelperClz, “CallbackHandler”, "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V”);`

`jstring string_data = env->NewStringUTF((const char*)"SOME_STRING_DATA");`

`jint int_data = 10; // some number`   

`env->CallVoidMethod(pctx->jniHelperObj, statusId, string_data, int_data);`

`env->DeleteLocalRef(string_data);`